# Porque esse código não funciona?

Tags: php

Tenho esse código:

```
function multiply(a, b) {
    return a * b
}
```

Queria saber por que ele não funciona?

Erro retornado:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /home/codewarrior/run.php on line 5

Comment: Cara, na verdade esse código é javascript ou php? tem certeza que é php? porque me parece ser javascript pelo jeito dele, pois variaveis PHP devem conter $ no inicio

Comment: @Paulo Roberto Pelo erro deve ser mesmo php

Comment: "Problemas ou perguntas reais que você encontrou" porque isso tá no tour então se não pode ter erro?

Answer (score 6):

Acredito que tirou o código [daqui](https://www.codewars.com/?language=php).

O que acontece é que está faltando algumas coisas básicas como o uso de `$` para indicar **variáveis** passadas como parâmetros:

> As variáveis no PHP são representadas por um cifrão ($) seguido pelo nome da variável.<sup>[1](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php)</sup>

E também está faltando `;` (ponto e vírgula) no final da segunda linha do seu programa:

> PHP requer que as instruções sejam terminadas com um ponto-e-vírgula ao final de cada comando.<sup>[1](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)</sup>

Por fim, você pode utilizar dessa maneira o seu código:

```
function multiply($a, $b) {
  return $a * $b;
}
```

Comment: Uzu, a correção do código iria fechar a excelente resposta!

Comment: @Bsalvo, fiz uma edição como sugerido.

Answer (score 1):

Porque você esqueceu de colocar `;` no final da linha.

```
function multiply($a, $b) {
  return $a * $b;
}
```

Inicialmente acreditei que o problema era em JavaScript pois suas variáveis estavam sem o `$` necessário para que o PHP reconheça como uma variável, mas na verdade a sua função está em PHP como segue a tag, então acredito que você tenha se confundido e estava programando JavaScript no PHP. (já passei por isso)

Então tenha em vista que para declarar e utilizar variáveis no PHP você tem de usar `$` no inicio de cada uma delas.

Comment: Faltou utilizar $ também, é necessário em PHP.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis rapaz eu JUREI que era em javascript, eu acredito que o OP também achava, pelo erro.

Comment: Não é PHP mesmo, a sintaxe é bem parecida, além disso observe o erro *PHP Parser error*

Comment: Sim eu vi aqui, só que talvez ele tenha se confundindo e tava programando js no php, como eu ja fiz algumas vezes